# No se porque el programa se cierra solo

Tags: c

, tiene como base 5 tickets para cada comida (desayuno, almuerzo y cena.) cada ticket está representado por 1 disponible, 0 usado, todos los tickets son inicializados como disponible.
Por cada comida que compre el estudiante, se debe descontar un ticket para el tipo de comida, debe validar si puede o no comprar si le queda ticket disponible.

Realice un programa que permite, a través de una función por proceso, realizar:

1. Verificar disponibilidad del ticket (por comida)`introducir el código aquí`
2. Calcular tickets disponibles y usados por comida.

Una vez que ya el usuario no desea realizar más ventas, imprima los siguientes totales:

1. Arreglos de tickets

Mi amigo me pidio que le ayudara ya que le salian otros problemas pero ahora cuando lo ejecuto y introdusco 1 2 o 3 el programa imprime el texto de la validacion y se cierra no se porque ocurre esto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int
ValidarTickets (int opc, int des[5], int alm[5], int cen[5] )
{
  int  res, d, t;
  t = 0;
  switch (opc)
    {
    case 1:
      for (d = 0; d < 5 ; d++)
    {
      if (des[d]= 1)
        {
          res = 1;
          t = t + 1;
        }
      else
        {
          res = 0;
        }
    }
      printf ("Tiene = %d tickets disponibles para el desayuno\n", t);
    case 2:
      for (d = 0; d < 5 ; d++)
    {
      if (alm[d] = 1)
        {
          res = 1;
          t = t + 1;
        }
      else
        {`introducir el código aquí`
          res = 0;
        }
    }
      printf ("Tiene = %d tickets disponibles para el almuerzo\n", t);
    case 3:
      for (d = 0; d < 5 ; d++)
    {
      if (cen[d] = 1)
        {
          res = 1;
          t = t + 1;
        }
      else
        {
          res = 0;
        }
    }
      printf ("Tiene = %d tickets disponibles para la cena\n", t);
      break;
      printf ("No ingreso el tipo de comida correcto\n");
    }
  return res;
}

  int main ()
  {
    int opc;
    char rs;
    
    int cc = 0;
    int ca = 0;
    int cd = 0;
    int td = 5;
    int ta = 5;
    int tc = 5;
    int nd = 0;
    int na = 0;
    int nc = 0;
    int desayuno[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};
    int almuerzo[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};
    int cena[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};
    int d;
    int comida;
    

    do
      {
    printf ("Que tipo de comida comer\n");
    printf ("1.Desayuno\n");
    printf ("2.Almuerzo\n");
    printf ("3.Cena\n");
    scanf ("%d", &opc);
    printf ("Se le verificara si posee tickets de la UTP ---->\n");
    comida = ValidarTickets (opc, desayuno[5], almuerzo[5],cena[5]);
    if (comida = 1)
      {
        printf ("Realizando la transaccion...\n");
        switch (opc)
          {
          case 1:
        for (d = 0; cd <5; cd++)
          {
            desayuno[d] = 0;
          }
        nd = nd + 1;
        td = td - 1;
        cd = cd + 1;
        printf ("Ya ha utilizado : %d tickets de esta comida\n", nd);
        printf
          ("Ahora tiene : %d tickets disponibles para el desayuno.\n",
           td);
          case 2:
        for (d = 0; ca <5; ca++)
          {
            almuerzo[d] = 0;
          }
        na = na + 1;
        ta = ta - 1;
        ca = ca + 1;
        printf ("Ya ha utilizado : %d tickets de esta comida\n", na);
        printf
          ("Ahora tiene : %d tickets disponibles para el almuerzo.\n",
           ta);
          case 3:
        for (d = 0; cc <5; cc++)
          {
            cena[d] = 0;
          }
        nc = nc + 1;
        tc = tc - 1;
        cc = cc + 1;
        printf ("Ya ha utilizado : %d tickets de esta comida\n", nc);
        printf ("Ahora tiene : %d tickets disponibles para la cena.\n",
            tc);
        break;
        printf ("Ingrese otro numero\n");
          }
      }
    printf ("Desea realizar otra transaccion? (s/n)\n");
    scanf ("%s", &rs);
      }while (rs == 's');
    


    printf ("La cantidad de tickets para el desayuno es: %d\n", td);
    for (d = 0; d <5; d++)
      {
    printf ("%d\n", desayuno[d]);
      }
    printf ("La cantidad de tickets para el almuerzo es: %d\n", ta);
    for (d = 0; d <5; d++)
      {
    printf ("%d\n", almuerzo[d]);
      }
    printf ("La cantidad de tickets para la cena es: %d\n", tc);
    for (d = 0; d <5; d++)
      {
    printf ("%d\n", cena[d]);
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `ValidarTickets (opc, desayuno[5], almuerzo[5],cena[5])`. Quitale los `[5]`. La funcion espera un `int*`, y tu le pasas un `int`. Me sorprende que eso solo genera un warning y no un error. Y adentro de todos tus `if`, estas usando `=`, que es el operador de asignacion. Tienes que usar `==`.

Answer (score 0):

En la línea 35 de tu programa tienes: `introducir el código aquí` dentro del `else`.

Una recomendación personal es que nombres a tus variables con nombres técnicos para que tu programa pueda ser leído por cualquier programador.

Si pides un arreglo como parámetro de una función, no es necesario especificar su tamaño, basta con solo abrir y cerrar corchetes. Ejemplo en tu función:

De:

`int ValidarTickets (int opc, int des[5], int alm[5], int cen[5])`

A:

`int ValidarTickets (int opc, int des[], int alm[], int cen[])`

---

Al final de cada `case` en el `switch` debes colocar la reservada `brake;` sino, se ejecutará cada caso del `switch`.

Y en el caso de que la opción ingresada no corresponda con ningún `case`, debes crear un `default:` para ese caso de error.

---

En fin, esta mi propuesta de solución a tu código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int ValidarTickets (int opc, int des[], int alm[], int cen[] ) {
    
  int  res, d, t;
  t = 0;
  
  switch (opc){
      
    case 1:
    
        for (d = 0; d < 5 ; d++) {
          
            if(des[d]= 1){
              res = 1;
              t = t + 1;
            } else {
              res = 0;
            }
            
        }
        
        printf ("Tiene = %d tickets disponibles para el desayuno\n", t);
        break;
        
    case 2:
        for (d = 0; d < 5 ; d++) {
            
            if (alm[d] = 1) {
              res = 1;
              t = t + 1;
            }else {
              res = 0;
            }
        }
        
        printf ("Tiene = %d tickets disponibles para el almuerzo\n", t);
        break;
        
    case 3:
        for (d = 0; d < 5 ; d++){
            if (cen[d] = 1) {
                res = 1;
                t = t + 1;
            } else {
                res = 0;
            }
            
        }
        
        printf ("Tiene = %d tickets disponibles para la cena\n", t);
        break;
        
    
    default: 
        printf ("No ingreso el tipo de comida correcto\n");
        break;
    }
    
  return res;
}

  int main () {
    int opc;
    char rs;
    
    int cc = 0;
    int ca = 0;
    int cd = 0;
    int td = 5;
    int ta = 5;
    int tc = 5;
    int nd = 0;
    int na = 0;
    int nc = 0;
    int desayuno[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};
    int almuerzo[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};
    int cena[5] = {1,1,1,1,1};
    int d;
    int comida;
    

    do {
        printf ("Que tipo de comida comer\n");
        printf ("1.Desayuno\n");
        printf ("2.Almuerzo\n");
        printf ("3.Cena\n");
        scanf ("%d", &opc);
        printf ("Se le verificara si posee tickets de la UTP ---->\n");
        comida = ValidarTickets (opc, desayuno, almuerzo, cena);
        
        if (comida = 1) {
            printf ("Realizando la transaccion...\n");
            
            switch (opc){
                case 1:
                
                    for (d = 0; cd <5; cd++) {
                        desayuno[d] = 0;
                    }
                    
                    nd = nd + 1;
                    td = td - 1;
                    cd = cd + 1;
                    
        
                    printf ("Ya ha utilizado : %d tickets de esta comida\n", nd);
                    printf ("Ahora tiene : %d tickets disponibles para el desayuno.\n",td);
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 2:
                
                    for (d = 0; ca <5; ca++){
                        almuerzo[d] = 0;
                    }
                    
                    na = na + 1;
                    ta = ta - 1;
                    ca = ca + 1;
                    
                    printf ("Ya ha utilizado : %d tickets de esta comida\n", na);
                    printf("Ahora tiene : %d tickets disponibles para el almuerzo.\n", ta);
                    
                    break;
                    
                case 3:
                
                    for (d = 0; cc <5; cc++) {
                        cena[d] = 0;
                    }
                    
                    nc = nc + 1;
                    tc = tc - 1;
                    cc = cc + 1;
                    printf ("Ya ha utilizado : %d tickets de esta comida\n", nc);
                    printf ("Ahora tiene : %d tickets disponibles para la cena.\n", tc);
                    
                    break;
                    
                default:    
                    printf ("Ingrese otro numero\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
      
        printf ("Desea realizar otra transaccion? (s/n)\n");
        scanf ("%s", &rs);
        
    }while (rs == 's');
    

    printf ("La cantidad de tickets para el desayuno es: %d\n", td);
    
    for (d = 0; d <5; d++) {
        printf ("%d\n", desayuno[d]);
    }
    
    printf ("La cantidad de tickets para el almuerzo es: %d\n", ta);
    
    for (d = 0; d <5; d++) {
        printf ("%d\n", almuerzo[d]);
    }
    
    printf ("La cantidad de tickets para la cena es: %d\n", tc);
    
    for (d = 0; d <5; d++) {
        printf ("%d\n", cena[d]);
    }
    
    getchar();
    getchar();
    
    return 0;
  }
```

---

**Te recomiendo identar tu código para una mayor legibilidad**

El código aún tiene cosillas que yo mejoraría, pero el código que te proporcioné cumple el objetivo que planteas.